# Can't Add a style file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. Now I've noticed that when I import a style file to my component, React adds a `<style> my styles </style>` to my `<head>` tag. How can I have a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">`  in my head **instead**?

**Here is what I Get(inline style)**
[image]

And this is what I want to happen when I import a CSS file.

[image]

I don't like to have all my styles, inline in **head** tag. How can I change this in React??

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or you've setup everything yourself with webpack?

Comment: I use create-react-app

Comment: Sorry but why would you do that? you can edit `public > index.html` and link your css file  to the `<head>`

Comment: @awran5 Cause it makes my head tag too busy. My head is full of meta tags I don't wanna make it more complex with inline styles

Answer (score 2):

You could put your css files in the public folder, and then add the links directly to `index.html`. You would need to use `%PUBLIC_URL%` to give it the right path though, ie

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles/app.css" />
```

Generally this isn't best practice though, and as recommended by React ([docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)) it is better for performance to import assets into js files, so that the stylesheets are minified and bundled by webpack.